# AS3 addEventListener not a recognized method in my custom class

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to have a Class called `Commands` that I can put different key presses and functions into that will control game states and variables for quick and easy game testing.  I'm trying this, but it's not working...

```
package gameTesting {
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

    public class Commands {

        public function Commands() {
            addEventListeners();
        }

        public function addEventListeners():void{
            addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDown);
        }

        public function keyDown(ke:KeyboardEvent):void{
            trace("key pressed");
        }

    }

}
```

which throws this error:

```
C:...\Commands.as, Line 15, Column 4    1180: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener.
```

So,  I tried having my class extend something that inherits the EventDispatcher methods:

```
//...
    public class Commands extends DisplayObject{
// ...
```

but I just get this error thrown from my main `.as` file when trying to instantiate this Class:

```
ArgumentError: Error #2012: Commands$ class cannot be instantiated.
```

I also tried throwing the `static` keyword around just for lols, but no dice.

What am I missing here?

*by the way, my reason for doing things this way is just so that I can remove this functionality (so users can't use it) by simply removing the line of code that instantiates this class.  I think it's pretty nifty, but if this seems asinine, by all means speak up!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to pass stage to Commands,so you can add addEventListener on stage.

```
import flash.display.Stage;

public class Commands {

    public function Commands(stage:Stage) {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDown);
    }

    public function keyDown(ke:KeyboardEvent):void{
        trace("key pressed");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and I get implicit coercion of type Class to unrelated type stage. (oh, i tried passing Stage first, now I see I should pass lower case stage)... I think this gets me closer.  I'll keep dinking and let you know

Comment: You could round out your answer by adding this: `var com:Commands = new Commands(stage);` could be called from the main doc.

Comment: I'm going to leave it unanswered for just a day to see if any other great insights trickle in :)

Comment: Ok.My answer is a simple way to work,or you can do some test By message input.

Comment: I was confused at first how to implement this since both `stage` and `Stage` are keywords.  But yeah, this is very simple, just my style.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Pan I don't understand  "do some test By message input", could you explain me what do You mean, by the way nice and clear answer!

Comment: I mean if your game could send message to other player, you can set up some gm command.Like  gold 9999, and your have a global variable to control if gm command could be used.

Comment: @Pan, I never tried this in as3, any details, example or useful links are welcome. THX.
Nicolas.

Comment: We use GM commands in game development,like add some items, add gold,but no code online. I think it's a common way to develop game.